# Error en ciclo for al intentar mostrar datos json en una tabla

Tags: javascript, json

Hola me podrían ayudar,
Tengo problemas para mostrar datos json en una tabla usando un for. no había tenido problemas con usando esta manera, hasta ahora.
Esta es una captura de pantalla del error en consola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Deseo mostrar la información aquí:

```
        <div class="container mb-3">
            <table class="table table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>id</th>
                        <th>Fecha</th>
                        <th>Origen</th>
                        <th>Tipo</th>
                        <th>Rating</th>
                        <th>Satisfacción</th>
                        <th>Puntaje</th>
                    </tr>   
                </thead>
                <tbody id="contenido">
                    <!--Datos del for-->
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Mis datos json son estos:

```
const datosJson = {
"paging": {
    "next": null,
},
"answers": [
    {
        "answered_survey": {
            "id": 2526985,
            "open_date": "2022-11-02 17:21:00",
            "answered_date": "2022-11-02 17:23:11"
            },
            "satisfaction": {
                "id": 1,
                "description": "Sobresaliente",
                "score": 4.93
        }
    }
  ]
};
```

Este es mi script ya he intentando de varias maneras pero no logro hacerlo funcionar:

```
  <script> 
  console.log(datosJson);
  console.log(datosJson.answers[0].answered_survey.id);//test
  var contenido = document.querySelector('#contenido');
  contenido.innerHTML = '';
  for(let respuesta of datosJson){
  contenido.innerHTML += `<tr><td>${datosJson.answers[0].answered_survey.id}</td></tr>`
  }
  </script>
```

Comment: for of es solo para arreglo por lo que debes usar `for( respuesta in datosJson.answers[0])`

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funcionó de esa manera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for of` solo sirve para `arrays` y tú estás intentando iterar sobre el `json`

Por lo que entiendo estás intentando iterar sobre las respuestas, por lo que deberías hacer.

```
for(let respuesta of datosJson.answers){
  contenido.innerHTML += `<tr><td>${respuesta.answered_survey.id}</td></tr>`
}
```

De esta forma iteras sobre el `array` `answers` del `json`